# What is the fastest way to copy a 2D array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, copy

I have to make a very large number of simulations on a `R*C` grid.

These simulations are altering the grid, so I need to copy my reference grid before each, and then apply my simulating function on the fresh new grid.

What is the fastest way to do this in Python?

---

*Since I have not found a similar question on StackOverflow, I did the tests myself and decided to post them here thinking they could be useful to other people.*

*The answer will be a community response so that other people can add new measurements with possibly other techniques.*

*If you add another method, remember to measure all the old tests and update them because the time depends on the computer used, avoid biasing the results.*

Comment: What kind of array? NumPy ndarray? python array? nested python list? some other array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used a bash variable for setting up the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) tests:

```
setup="""
R = 100
C = 100
from copy import deepcopy
import numpy as np
ref = [[i for i in range(C)] for _ in range(R)]
ref_np = np.array(ref)
cp = [[100 for i in range(C)] for _ in range(R)]
cp_np = np.array(cp)
"""
```

Just for convenience, I also set a temporary alias `pybench`:

```
alias pybench='python3.5 -m timeit -s "$setup" $1'
```

---

## Python 3

*Python 3.5.0+ (default, Oct 11 2015, 09:05:38)*

- **Deepcopy:**

  ```
  >>> pybench "cp = deepcopy(ref)"
  100 loops, best of 3: 8.29 msec per loop
  ```
- **Modifying pre-created array using index:**

  ```
  >>> pybench \
  "for y in range(R):
      for x in range(C):
          cp[y][x] = ref[y][x]"
  1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 msec per loop
  ```
- **Nested list comprehension:**

  ```
  >>> pybench "cp = [[x for x in row] for row in ref]"
  1000 loops, best of 3: 390 usec per loop
  ```
- **Slicing:**

  ```
  >>> pybench "cp = [row[:] for row in ref]"
  10000 loops, best of 3: 45.8 usec per loop
  ```
- **NumPy copy:**

  ```
  >>> pybench "cp_np = np.copy(ref_np)"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 6.03 usec per loop
  ```
- **Copying to pre-created NumPy array:**

  ```
  >>> pybench "np.copyto(cp_np, ref_np)"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 4.52 usec per loop
  ```

---

There is nothing very surprising in these results, as you might have guessed, use NumPy is enormously faster, especially if one avoids creating a new table each time.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer from Delgan, numpy copy's documentation says to use numpy.ndarray.copy as the preferred method. So for now, without doing a timing test, I will use numpy.ndarray.copy

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html