# Why is slicing so much faster than deepcopy in python?

Tags: python, copy

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968157/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-copy-a-2d-array-in-python) and other sources, copying by slicing is 1000x faster than copy.deepcopy.

Why is this? What is it about the way that python implements slicing and deepcopy that causes such a huge difference? Is it something with the way python manages memory?

I don't think that slicing is making a shallow copy.
For example, with code like:

```
    cur = [[0] * (2) for _ in xrange(2)]
    cur2 = [row[:] for row in cur]
    cur2[0][0] = "foo"
    print(cur)
    print(cur2)
```

I get:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0]] # cur
[['foo', 0], [0, 0]] # cur2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because slicing is doing a shallow copy, not a deep copy?

Comment: See my edit: I don't think it's doing a shallow copy, since when I change cur2, cur is not changed. Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

Slicing returns a shallow copy as opposed to a deep copy. This means that objects inside the container are not reproduced in memory - only a reference to that object is retained.

The linked answer is essentially a list of lists:

```
x = [[0,1,2],
     [3,4,5],
     [6,7,8]]
```

Slicing the list (e.g. `x[:1]`) will return a copy of the list, but it won't copy the individual elements of that list. Modifying elements in the slice will in turn modifying the elements from the original list.

`copy.deepcopy` copies the original list, but also any nested elements. That takes more work, and is the reason why it is slower. Good note is that deep copies are only needed when elements are mutable. In the case of immutable objects, such as strings, a deepcopy is not necessary - a shallow copy would suffice.

Comment: Hm, but if I run this code: 
        cur = [[0] * (2) for _ in xrange(2)]
        cur2 = [row[:] for row in cur]
        cur2[0][0] = "foo"
        print(cur)
        print(cur2)     
then the result is:
cur: [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
cur2: [['foo', 0], [0, 0]]   which would not be the case if it were a shallow copy.

Comment: @user1552700 Re-read the code. You didn't do a copy of the high-level list (i.e. `cur[:]`, you made a copy of each nested list, hence your list comprehension `row[:] for row in cur`. These are all different lists. If you're interested, check out identity testing (`id` function), and read the internals on slicing.

Answer (score 1):

.deepcopy makes a new object and then copies each object from the original list into that new object. Slicing performs the same function as .copy does (a shallow copy), which makes a new object but then only inserts references to the original list's objects. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html